# Prove from first principles that

Tags: real-analysis

$$\frac{x^2-12}{x-5} \rightarrow -4 \text{ as } x \rightarrow 4$$

Do I need to fix an $\epsilon > 0$ and do something like

$$x \geq N \implies |\frac{x^2-12}{x-5} - -4| < \epsilon $$

I am not sure how to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost... but $x$ is approaching $4$, so you don't want $x \geq N$. Instead you want to say if $x$ is close enough to $4$, then $\frac{x^2-12}{x-5}$ is within $\epsilon$ of $-4$. I.e., for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-4|<\delta$, then $\left|\frac{x^2-12}{x-5}-(-4)\right|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a $\delta > 0$ so that if $|x-4| < \delta$, then

$$ \left| \frac{ x^2 - 12 }{x - 5 } + 4 \right| < \epsilon $$

We see that the quantity inside the absolute value simplifies to

$$ \frac{ x^2 + 4x -32 }{x-5} = \frac{ (x+8)(x-4) }{x-5}  $$

If we assume first that $|x-4| < 1$, then $|x+8| = |x-4+12| \leq |x-4| + 12 < 13$ and how do we bound $\frac{1}{x-5}$?